# Auto simplifications of power products

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

Mathematica automatically simplifies `Exp[a]Exp[b]` to `Exp[a+b]`. The problem is now that I can't do this `Exp[a]Exp[b]/.Exp[a]->c` for example. How to solve this kind of problem?

In particular I want something like this to work `Exp[x_+y_]//.Exp[x]Exp[y]/.Exp[some_pattern]->c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `HoldForm` and `HoldPattern` for your purpose. Suppose you want to replace `Exp[i_Integer]` by `c`, then you can do the following:

```
replace[e_] := e /. Exp[x_ + y_] :> HoldForm[Exp[x] Exp[y]] /. HoldPattern@Exp[a_Integer] -> c

replace[Exp[1 + b] + Exp[2 + d]]
(* c exp(b) + c exp(d) *)
```

Comment: That's it. The only thing left is `// FixedPoint[ReleaseHold, #] &` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only applicable to easy examples!

You could try to find the inverse function and give the corresponding replacement rule:

```
Exp[a]Exp[b]/.a->Log[c]
```

But you have to be sure, that you don't miss special cases, when using the inverse function.

Comment: What if I got some pattern instead of `a`? `Exp[A a]Exp[b]/.Exp[A _]->c`

Comment: As I noted, this is only for easy examples. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633236/replace-inside-held-expression) could be interesting for you. Though it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like

```
E^a E^b /. E^(a + b_.) :> c E^b
(* c E^b *)
```

which can be generalized to

```
E^(a A) E^b /. E^(a _ + b_.) :> c E^b
(* c E^b *)
```